# How can I determine asymptotic growth of binomial coefficients?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, asymptotics

Say I have a binomial coefficient $y=\binom{5n+3}{n+2}$ or $y=\binom{n^2+4}{3n}$ something of the sorts in terms of the variable $n$. How can I determine $f$ so that $y = O(f)$?

Is there a general method for this sort of thing.  I have only ever seen $O$-notation in a computer science setting and its treatment was not concerned with deriving anything except the bounds for "simple" functions like logarithms and polynomials.  As a side question, what would be a good resource to learn further methods to find $O$ of more complex functions?  I understand the formal definition, but Im unsure how to use it practically.

My apologies if this is a stupid question. Its not homework.

Comment: It's imprecise to say "determine O(y)."  What you want is to write down some nice function f such that y = O(f).  (Of course what you _really_ want is probably to write down some nice function f such that y = Theta(f).)

Comment: You might also want to take a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6784/

Comment: @qiaochu yes, thats what I meant, edited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) in $\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your second question is to read Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik's [Concrete Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025), at least for simpler practical examples.  For complicated sequences it can be extremely difficult and in many cases open to find asymptotics, e.g. for Ramsey-theoretic sequences, so you'll have to narrow the scope of your question a little to get a reasonable answer.

Comment: Specifically, look at Chapter 9 of *Concrete Mathematics*.